# What's wrong with my level 13 solution? ( "stick to left side" implementation attempt)

Tags: untrusted

So I'm struggling with *Untrusted* as a (super fun!) homework. I got stuck at level 13, after 2 hours I glanced at the other topic about it and tried to implement the "stick to the left side" method, but it doesn't seem to work.

Could you guys tell me what's wrong? There might be some pretty fundamental mistakes as my first encounter with JavaScript was on Tuesday.

```
var direction;

if ( me.getX() == 1 & me.getY() == 1 ){
    
    if ( me.canMove('right') )
        direction = 0;
    else
        direction = 1;
}

moveRobot( direction );
direction = getDirection();  

function moveRobot( direction ) {

    if ( me.canMove( getDirectionName( direction ) ) ){
        me.move( getDirectionName( direction ) ) ;
    }
    else if ( !me.canMove( getDirectionName( direction ) )
    & me.canMove( getDirectionName( (direction + 1) % 4) ) ){
            me.move( getDirectionName( (direction + 1) % 4) );
            direction = (direction + 1) % 4;
    }
    else {
        me.move( getDirectionName( (direction + 2) % 4) );
        direction = (direction + 2) % 4;
    }
          
}

function getDirection( ){

    if ( me.canMove( getDirectionName( direction ) ) ){
        return direction;
    }
    else if ( !me.canMove( getDirectionName( direction ) )
    & me.canMove( getDirectionName( (direction + 1) % 4) ) ){
        return (direction + 1) % 4;
    }
    else
        return (direction + 2) % 4; 
}

function getDirectionName( direction ){

    if ( direction == 0 )
        return 'right';
    else if ( direction == 1 )
        return 'down';
    else if ( direction == 2 )
        return 'left';  
    else    
        return 'up';          
}
```

Comment: This is on-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @PythonMaster, just to clarify, this is still on topic, here. While StackOverflow can help you with just about any programming-related issue, we still consider it on topic when the problem is also game-related. If you need to solve the programming issue to progress in the game, it is most certainly game-related. [tag:vim-adventures] is another example of a code-based game

Comment: @PythonMaster  I thought that this question is difficult to be stated on Stack Overflow properly. After all you need to play this game to be able to see what's inside level 13.

Comment: Oh, it's a game... Wish I could retract my downvote...

Comment: The game is tagged in the question, @PythonMaster. The question still looks like it could do with a tidy edit, once edited you can change your vote

Comment: For people who came here while searching the internet for alternative solutions, there is a page compiling different nice-and-short solutions for each level:  https://gist.github.com/mhasdf/40363e0c1c807663d8c6ccb797aa94fa

Answer (score 1):

<strike>**1.** I think a stick to left side implementation of this problim is not possible. If you want to stick to the left side you have to know where the left side is. So yout have to know what the direction of your last move was. Since the variables of the function</strike>

> 'behavior': function (me) {...}

"reset" every time the function gets called, this is not easy to implement.

**EDIT:** See comment section.

**2.** You are only setting the value of direction when x = 1 and y = 1 so it only deos something if those coords are right. Since the robot moves the coords change.

> if ( **me.getX() == 1 & me.getY() == 1** ){
>
> ```
> if ( me.canMove('right') )
>     direction = 0;
> else
>     direction = 1; }
> ```

Else direction is unset and nothing will work.

You would change it to the following:

> moveRobot( direction );
>   direction = getDirection();

Note:
If you cannot solve a level, don't search for the answers of others, because you will lose the fun of that game. If necessary cheat through and solve the level later:

> 1. Open console (`F12`)
>  2. Enter: "localStorage.levelReached = `LEVEL_NUMBER`"
>  3. Reload page

Comment: This isn't true; the `behavior` function gets called with the same object every time, so you can use that object to store data.

Comment: Agree with @pppery. I successfully implemented a stick-to-left-side solution by simply adding a property to the `me` object. Start with something like `if(!me.leftSide) {me.leftSide = 'up';}`, and then `me.leftSide` will be defined and will remember its value between `behavior` calls.

Comment: Thank you for your corrections, I updated the answer to point to the comment section.